# XML sitemap module Drupal is not updating... why?

Tags: xml, drupal, module, drupal-7, sitemap

I have drupal 7.x and the module `XML sitemap` 7.x-2.3
I noticed that i have 900 nodes but only 480 are indexed...

I clean the cache, run cron but nothing... the xml sitemap is not update.

**Minimum sitemap lifetime**  is setting on

```
 "No minimum".
```

I hope that the answer is not difficult for me :/

I don't understand why doesn't work. I hope that you can help me to solve this issue...

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: This would be a better fit for [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Check in the content type settings or xmlsitemap settings if the module is included or not.